# Trying to apply CRUD functionality to python project

Tags: python, django

So I'm building a real estate website for school. And one of the requirements is to have CRUD functionality on the front end for admins. But before i knew that i created in the backend admin page, all the fields that need to be filled before a listing can be published.

But now i need to display all of the fields i created on the backend admin page to show  on the front end. I've tried writing the code to display it but its not really working. Im only seeing the submit button.

Im new to coding and stack overflow, so please do let me know if you need anything els from me or if ive done something wrong.

these are the fields that should be filled and show up in the front end for realtors to publish, edit and remove a listing:

models.py

```
class Listing(models.Model):
    realtor = models.ForeignKey(Realtor, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    bedrooms = models.IntegerField()
    bathrooms = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2, decimal_places=1)
    garage = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    sqft = models.IntegerField()
    
    photo_main = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/')
    photo_1 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)
    photo_2 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)
    photo_3 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)
    photo_4 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)
    photo_5 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)
    photo_6 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    list_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
```

This is the code that Ive tried writing to display the code above on the front end so it can be edited.

forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from listings.models import Listing 


class listingForm():
    class Meta:
        model = Listing
        fields = '__all__'
```

create_listing.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}

<form action="" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

views.py

```
def createListing(request):

    form = listingForm()
    context = {'form': form}

    return render(request, 'accounts/create_listing.html')
```

Comment: `class listingForm():` should be `class listingForm(ModelForm):`

Comment: I tried that, nothing changed when i did that..

Comment: And `return render(request, 'accounts/create_listing.html')` should be `return render(request, 'accounts/create_listing.html', {'form': form})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't pass in the context to the render function, the code should look like this:

```
def createListing(request):

    form = listingForm()
    context = {'form': form}

    return render(request,'accounts/create_listing.html', context)
```

Also a suggestion for your code is optimising the photos for your Listing model, here is a good material to watch: https://youtu.be/-0nYBqY9i5w